# Image Button In XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Could someone help with this.

Im trying to make the following code so that i can inject what ever image i want into this button style. as this button style is used throughout the whole application

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ButtonIsChecked">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Content}" Name="CheckBox_Logon" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsChecked="False">
                            <CheckBox.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                                    <WrapPanel>
                                        <Image 
                                               Source="/AdminUltimate;component/Images/Icons/Windows.ico" 
                                               Width="15" Margin="3" 
                                               Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, ElementName=DisableIcons}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </WrapPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </CheckBox.Template>
                        </CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Current Usage

```
<Button Content="Login" Style="{StaticResource ButtonIsChecked}"/>
```

i would like to do something like

```
<Button Content="Login" Style="{StaticResource ButtonIsChecked}" imgsrc="Pathtoimage"/>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Something quick and easy to use to piggy back a dependency string through is [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ButtonIsChecked">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="/Default/Image/Path.jpg"/>
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Content}" Name="CheckBox_Logon" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsChecked="False">
                            <CheckBox.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                                    <WrapPanel>
                                        <Image 
                                               Source="{TemplateBinding Tag}" 
                                               Width="15" Margin="3" 
                                               Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, ElementName=DisableIcons}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </WrapPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </CheckBox.Template>
                        </CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Then implement like;

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonIsChecked}" Tag="/AdminUltimate;component/Images/Icons/Windows.ico"/>
```

Hope this helps.